# How can I use commands when connecting computers through socket?

Tags: python, sockets

I set up a python script to connect two computers with sockets and am trying to run commands from terminal. The script will hopefully run the commands on the host onto the client but it doesnt recognize any commands. My code for the server is

```
import socket

HOST = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 12345

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))

server_socket.listen(5)
print("\n[*] Listening on port " +str(PORT)+ ", waiting for connexions.")


client_socket, (client_ip, client_port) = server_socket.accept()
print("[*] Client " +client_ip+ " connected.\n")


while True:
    try:
        command = input(client_ip+ ">")
        if(len(command.split()) != 0):
            client_socket.send(bytes(command, 'utf-8'))
        else:
            continue
    except(EOFError):
            print("Invalid input, type 'help' to get a list of implemented commands.\n")
            continue

    if(command == "quit"):
        break

    data = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print((data + b"\n"))

client_socket.close()
```

and the client is

```
import socket
import subprocess, os

HOST = ''
PORT = 12345

connexion_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
connexion_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
connexion_socket.connect((HOST, PORT))
print('\n[*] Connected to " +HOST+ " "on port" +str(PORT+) ".\n"')

while True:

    command = str(connexion_socket.recv(1024))
    split_command = command.split()
    print('Received command : ' +command)

    if command == 'quit':
        break

    if(command.split()[0] == 'cd'):
        if len(command.split()) == 1:
            connexion_socket.send((os.getcwd()))
        elif len(command.split()) == 2:
            try:
                os.chdir(command.split()[1])
                connexion_socket.send(('Changed Directory to' + os.getcwd()))
            except:
                connexion_socket.send(str.encode('No such directory : ' +os.getcwd()))

    else:

        proc = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

        stdout_value = proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()
        print(str(stdout_value) + '\n')

        if(stdout_value != ''):
            connexion_socket.send(stdout_value)
        else:
            connexion_socket.send(command+ ' does not return anything')
```

Whenever I try to run a command like 'ipconfig' or 'cd' i get the error

"is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n\n"

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: try to print out what you received at receiver's side? maybe you receive some extra cause of encoding.

Comment: Why do you repeatedly use `command.split()` when you already saved the result of that in the `split_command` variable?

Comment: @WhereisourMonica sorry, heres the other side ```ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine```

Comment: not meaning that, i means when you send you text to receiver, you decode then ```print()``` it out,and then execute it. so you can see what you executed.

Comment: @WhereisourMonica i dont know what you mean by that

Comment: oh nothing, i see it:```print('Received command : ' +command)```

Comment: @WhereisourMonica ah